# Searching a listBox for a specified string VB6

Tags: search, vb6, listbox

I have a listbox called lstSerial and a textbox called txtSerials.  What I want to do is search lstSerial for the string that's entered in txtSerials.  I'm using VB6 in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, and I'm having a terrible time finding documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@AlexK's answer is technically correct - yes - it will work, but it's not the preferred way to go.  There is an API call for this very purpose:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
     (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As _
     Integer, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

'constants for searching the ListBox
Private Const LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT = &H1A2
Private Const LB_FINDSTRING = &H18F

'function to get find an item in the Listbox
Public Function GetListBoxIndex(hWnd As Long, SearchKey As String, Optional FindExactMatch As Boolean = True) As Long

    If FindExactMatch Then
        GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, -1, ByVal SearchKey)
    Else
        GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRING, -1, ByVal SearchKey)
    End If

End Function
```

So you want to do this:

```
lstSerial.ListIndex = GetListBoxIndex(lstSerial.hWnd, txtSerials.Text)
```

[Source](http://www.vbrad.com/pf.asp?p=source/src_search_lists.htm)

Comment: I find this best solution since it is faster grabbing data each of the data in the listbox.

Answer (score 6):

Docs; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267225(v=VS.60).aspx

```
dim find as string,i as long,found as boolean
find=txtSerials.text

for i=0 to lstserial.listcount - 1
    if strcomp(find, lstSerial.list(i), vbTextcompare)=0 then
        found = true
        lstSerial.setfocus
        lstSerial.listindex= i
        exit for
    end if
next

if not found then msgbox "not found ..."
```

Comment: +1 I use this method too, I've never found it's performance to be bad so prefer it over the API calls