# VB6: How to Search Listbox using API and get all matchs?

Tags: vb6

I have a listbox with a few thousand items. The code below given by [@AngryHacker  in this threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265623/searching-a-listbox-for-a-specified-string-vb6) work perfect if i want to get the 1st match. But sometimes i have multiple items with the same data. So, i'd like to get all the match, how to do it?

oh, actually, its something like this:
aa4
sds
aa5
aa6
fdf
dsf

From the list, i want to get the index of the items starting with "aa"

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
     (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As _
     Integer, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

'constants for searching the ListBox
Private Const LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT = &H1A2
Private Const LB_FINDSTRING = &H18F

'function to get find an item in the Listbox
Public Function GetListBoxIndex(hWnd As Long, SearchKey As String, Optional FindExactMatch As Boolean = True) As Long

    If FindExactMatch Then
        GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, -1, ByVal SearchKey)
    Else
        GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRING, -1, ByVal SearchKey)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you have that many items in a listbox? The listbox is for presenting options to the user they can select, and scrolling through thousands of them seems like a very long process. (Allowing duplicates in the first place also doesn't seem like a wise UI decision, as you can't tell which one they're selecting if you have two that are the same for them to choose, and if you don't need to tell them apart then you don't need to display them both in the first place.)

Comment: Well, yes, listbox is too bad for too many item, but i have not found any other solution to that since i'm using vb6. I'd like to know if there is an alternative to listbox

Comment: You still didn't answer his question. A listbox is for a user interface. Why would you need thousands of items in your listbox?

Comment: Yes, i wanted user interface :)
Btw, it not always in thousands, sometimes it may be in 100s
The listcount depend on the user input, it performs permutation and searches in a huge database

Comment: Btw, @Ken, sorry for replying wrong + late :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize the fact that `wParam` for [LB_FINDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775187.aspx) and [LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775189.aspx) messages lets the caller to specify the first item to be searched:

> *wParam*
>
> The zero-based index of the item before the first item to be searched. When the search reaches the bottom of the list box, it continues searching from the top of the list box back to the item specified by the wParam parameter. If wParam is – 1, the entire list box is searched from the beginning.

So your `GetListBoxIndex` takes the following form (note `StartIndex` argument instead of hardcoded `-1`):

```
'LB_ constants
Private Const LB_ERR = -1
Private Const LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT = &H1A2
Private Const LB_FINDSTRING = &H18F

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" _
    Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long _
    , ByVal wMsg As Long _
    , ByVal wParam As Integer _
    , ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

Public Function GetListBoxIndex(hWnd As Long _
    , SearchKey As String _
    , StartIndex As Long _
    , Optional FindExactMatch As Boolean = True) As Long
    If FindExactMatch Then
        GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, StartIndex, SearchKey)
    Else
        GetListBoxIndex = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_FINDSTRING, StartIndex, SearchKey)
    End If
End Function
```

The rest depends on what you intend to do with the results afterwards. Below is simple test that merely prints results to Immediate window:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    PrintAllMatches List1.hWnd, Text1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    List1.AddItem "aa1"
    List1.AddItem "bbb"
    List1.AddItem "aa2"
End Sub

Private Sub PrintAllMatches(hWnd As Long, SearchKey As String)
    Dim firstMatch As Long, nextMatch As Long
    nextMatch = GetListBoxIndex(hWnd, SearchKey, -1, False)
    If nextMatch = LB_ERR Then
        Debug.Print "Not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    firstMatch = nextMatch
    Do
        Debug.Print "Match is at index " & nextMatch
        nextMatch = GetListBoxIndex(hWnd, SearchKey, nextMatch, False)
    Loop While nextMatch <> firstMatch
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case like this how to solve the following code,

```
Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst Adodc1.Recordset.Find "DEBTOR_CODE = '" & Text11.Text & "'" If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF = True Or Adodc1.Recordset.BOF = True Then MsgBox "Record Not Found!", vbApplicationModal Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst Me.Combo1.SetFocus Me.Combo1.ListIndex = Me.Text11.Text End If
```

i have to search debtor_code and each debtor has multiple addresses, i need to get the multiple answers in a combo box